# How to loop thrrough a 2D array diagonally in java

Tags: java, loops, multidimensional-array

I need to loop through a 2D Java array diagonally both ways (front and back). I have been looking for a code that can help me to do this but I have not been able to find. For instance if I have

```
A B C D E 
E F G H I 
J K L M N
```

I need a code that can loop this array and find all the possible diagonals i.e. AFL, EK, J CHN, EHL, DGK, etc

Comment: How would you do it manually? Implement that in code. (And I would have expected JBGM, for whatever that's worth.)

Comment: You have been "looking for code".  Did you try "writing code"?

Answer (score 0):

My first idea, untested:

```
int offsetX = ...;
int offsetY = ...;
Object[] matrix = ...;

for (int i = 0; i + Math.max(offsetX, offsetY) < Math.min(matrix.length, matrix[0].length); ++i)
{
    Object o = matrix[offsetY + i][offsetX + i];
}
```

Typically, only one of those two offsets can be non-zero, in your situation.
Flip som signs and modify the boundary checks to create other diagonals.

Comment: i would look at this soon

Comment: I finally used array shifting to left and right to get it. Thanks for the help anyway